# How to get the same key and different value in nested array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this post and get method inside the child.

```
$array1 = [
    "attribute" => "MySchool",
    "child" => 
        [
            "method" => "GET",
            "child" => [
                "attribute" => "school",
                "child" => [
                    [
                        "attribute" => "harvard"
                    ],                    
                ],
            ],
        ],
        [
            "method" => "POST",
            "child" => [
                "attribute" => "school",
                "child" => [
                    [
                        "attribute" => "stanford"
                    ],                    
                ],
            ],
        ],
]
```

```
$array2 = array(
    0 => "GET"
    1 => "school"
    2 => "harvard"
);
```

Now I just want the method `get` and its attribute value.
So I want a result of array just like this:

```
array(
0 => "MySchool"
1 => "get"
2 => "school"
3 => "harvard"
)
```

Comment: You want to have the two arrays in one with the same keys ?

Comment: what i want is i will get only myschool > get > school > harvard to array. i try array_walk_recursive() it will also return the post

Comment: What have you tried to accomplish this?

Comment: i try array_walk_recursive() it will also return the post. I only want get

Comment: @BenchBoy Please take a look at my snippet, with a combination of array_walk_recursive and I think your array is wrong. Once compare my structure with yours.

Comment: @DrakulaPredatorم Illegal string offset 'method' i think you mean key?

Comment: parent `"child" =>` have two sub-arrays get and post right? If yes, that should wrap to parent array, which is not the case with your array structure, I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the snippet for you,

```
/**
 * Function to fetch array with type
 *
 * @param      array   $array  The array
 * @param      string  $slug   The slug
 *
 * @return     array   custom array
 */
function custom($array, $slug)
{
    $res = [];
    if (is_array($array)) {
        // default attribute I assign to result as first attribute
        $res[] = $array['attribute'];
        foreach ($array['child'] as $k => $v) {
            if ($v['method'] == $slug) {
                $res[] = strtolower($v['method']);
                array_walk_recursive($v['child'], function ($item, $k1) use (&$res) {
                    if ($k1 == 'attribute') {
                        $res[] = $item;
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
    return $res;
}
$slug = 'GET';
$temp = custom($array1, $slug);
print_r($temp);
$slug = 'POST';
$temp = custom($array1, $slug);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/7JZ1J)

Output for **GET**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => MySchool
    [1] => get
    [2] => school
    [3] => harvard
)
```

For post

```
Array
(
    [0] => MySchool
    [1] => post
    [2] => school
    [3] => stanford
)
```

Comment: Illegal string offset 'method'

Comment: have you checked my demo for change in the structure of an array?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the key value of 'method' is GET then extract the elements you need.

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
    if ($key === 'attribute') $result[] = $value;
    if ($key === 'child' && $value['method'] === 'GET') {
        $result[] = $value['method'];
        $result[] = $array1['child']['child']['attribute'];
        $result[] = $array1['child']['child']['child'][0]['attribute'];
    }
}
print_r($result);
/*
 * Output: 
 * Array
 * (
 *     [0] => MySchool
 *     [1] => GET
 *     [2] => school
 *     [3] => harvard
 * )
 */
```

Answer (score 0):

If the response is always in the same format.
You can format the array with this code :

```
$result = [
    $array1["attribute"],
    $array1["child"]["method"],
    $array1["child"]["attribute"]
    $array1["child"]["child"]["attribute"]
];
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try the following:

```
 $result = getArray($array1);

function getArray($array, $new_array = [])
{
    $result = [];
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if ($key === 'attribute'
            || $key === 'method') {
            $new_array[] = $value;
        }
    }
    if (isset($array['child'])
        && is_countable($array['child'])
        && !isset($array['child'][0])
) {
        getArray($array['child'], $new_array);
    }
    elseif(isset($array['child'][0])) {
        getArray($array['child'][0], $new_array);
    } else {
        return print_r($new_array);
    }

}
```